# Incremental Upload data from sql server to Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, msbi

Our Raw Data is in SQL SERVER,Data keep on growing,Growth rate is high,We need to load the data incrementally to Redshift for Analytics.Can you please point out me a good practice to load the data.How feasible with SSIS to load directly to Redshift (with out S3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be impractical to load from SQL Server to Redshift without landing the data on S3. You can try loading via SSH but, of course, SSH on Windows is not well supported.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-from-remote-hosts.html

I did a presentation a while back on what we discovered when migrating from SQL Server to Redshift. One of the things we discovered was that SSIS was not very useful for interacting with AWS services.

http://blog.joeharris76.com/2013/09/migrating-from-sql-server-to-redshift.html

Finally, you could look into some of the commercial "replication" tools that automate the process of incrementally updating Redshift from an on-premise database. I hear good things about Attunity.

http://www.attunity.com/products/attunity-cloudbeam/amazon-redshift

Comment: My idea is i want load data to S3 with SSIS,then i want copy the S3 to Redshift tables.is there any open source tool or implementation for copying S3 to Redshift with Automation.

Comment: You have to create something from scratch unfortunately. We use CMD scripts (using the AWS CLI) that are run from SQL Server using `xp_cmdshell`. You could probably get SSIS to run the scripts if you prefer. But it's the scripts themselves which are the hard work.